How do I color my annotations and open the note tab in 4.2?
In a tutorial I am watching which uses Blender 4.0, while in the annotations tab there is this little bar on the top left corner that lets you change the color and access the Note drop down menu.

But this little bar is no where to be seen for me. Was it removed? Is it hidden somewhere? Here is my screen for reference.


That toolbar only appears after you've made the first annotation stroke. It's the same in Blender 4.0 (and below) and 4.2.
